# How do I separate and unpack tuples exported from SQLite database?

Tags: discord.py

I can't figure out how to separate and unpack tuples from SQLite Database.

I tried to unpack the tuple but couldn't understand how to actually separate it. I researched it but couldn't find any answers to my question. I'm relatively new to d.py and completely new to sqlite, so if you can, please provide an example or explanation of how I can unpack and separate the tuples provided.
What I have that works but isn't unpacked or separated:

```
async def _view_reports(ctx: discord.interactions.Interaction, user_name:str):
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM reports WHERE user_reported = ?", (user_name,)) 
  data = cursor.fetchall()
  loggedreports = discord.Embed(title="Reports Fetched!", color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
  loggedreports.description=f"{data}"
  await ctx.response.send_message(embed=loggedreports, ephemeral=True)
```

What the database looks like:
[What the database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z9ps.png)
and what it looks like when it outputs on discord:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX37s.png)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fetchall` with your cursor, you will get back a list of all matching rows. Each row contains the columns you selected (in your case all of them because of the `*`) in tuple form.

If your database would be more populated, with multiple matching rows, your `data` may look like this:

```py
[(1234567, 'user1', 'report'), (2345678, 'user1', 'report2'), (3456789, 'user1', 'x')]
```

You can just index into those, for example to get the first matching row's report reason you could use `data[0][2]`, but this would be pretty tedious, obfuscated and error prone.

Instead, in your use case I think it would make sense to loop over the matching rows, and then deconstruct the tuple in the loop, something like this maybe:

```py
data = cursor.fetchall()

for row in data:
    (staff, user, reason) = row
    # Do something with that data.
```